# Creating address and getting public address from private

Tags: addresses, ethereumjs

Just for learning I am trying, using javascript & ethereum, to create an address and get public key from private key without using a library like web3.

Anyone has tried to do this? any resources you can point me out?

Comment: "without using a library like web3" Which libraries are you willing to use and which not? Are you intending to implement elliptic curve cryptography from scratch using no libraries? Or is it specifically `web3.js` you want to avoid, or something else?

Comment: @smarx thanks for replying. My idea is to use near to none libraries, I think for crypto I will need to use them right?

Comment: You don't *need* to. The libraries are written in JavaScript themselves, so certainly you can write your own code that uses no libraries. But it would be a big waste of time. It's hard to know how to help here unless you explain your goals. (*Why* do you want to use "near to none libraries?")

Comment: @smarx my idea is to understand the whole process involved. Something like creating a web page with good old C ;)

Comment: The process is: 1) generate a random number, 2) generate the corresponding public key, 3) hash with keccak256 to obtain the Ethereum address. Unless you're looking to implement the crypto yourself, there's not much code to write.

Comment: @smarx maybe you can help me with this question please?: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/35573/creating-an-offline-address-creator-for-ethereum