# Get Token Balance without using nodejs

Tags: tokens, javascript, balances

I am trying to get Token Balance using plain javascript, no nodejs or web3.

With web3 and nodejs I can do:

```
exports.getTokenConfirmedBalance = function(node, query, abi) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            var provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider(node.url);
            var w3 = new web3(provider);

            var tokenContract = new w3.eth.Contract(abi, query.token_address, {from: query.pub_address});

            tokenContract.methods.balanceOf(query.pub_address).call().then(function (balance) {
                resolve(balance);

            }).catch(function(error) {
                reject(error)
            })

        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            reject(error.message);
        }
    })
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call, but you'll have to encode the function name and parameter. Should just be the first 4 bytes of `keccak256("balanceOf(address)") ` followed by the address, all hex encoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`eth_call`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call):

```
const tokenAddress = "0x123abc";
const account = "0x456def";

// Hex encoding needs to start with 0x.
// First comes the function selector, which is the first 4 bytes of the
//   keccak256 hash of the function signature.
// ABI-encoded arguments follow. The address must be left-padded to 32 bytes.
const data = '0x' +
  keccak_256.hex('balanceOf(address)').substr(0, 8) +
  '000000000000000000000000' + account.substr(2);     // chop off the 0x

// You can send this to any node.
fetch('https://mainnet.infura.io/APIKeyGoesHere', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    jsonrpc: "2.0",
    id: 1,
    method: "eth_call",
    params: [{
      to: tokenAddress,
      data: data,
    }, 'latest'],
  }),
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
}).then(response =>
  response.json()
).then(json =>
  console.log(json.result)
);
```

Comment: is not needed to pass ABI to getTokenBalance?

Comment: What is `getTokenBalance`?

Comment: that is a function I wrote :D, sorry, I was trying to ask if when getting balance of a ERC20 Token, we do not need to send ABI too?, I send it when using web3

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The ABI tells you what functions are available. We already know that `balanceOf` is available, since that's part of the interface of an ERC20 token.

Comment: I am newbie on this, thanks for the explanation, you rock!

Comment: Response is 66 characters long, in example I am getting: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006c6b935b8bbd400000, do I have to cut any characters?

Comment: What I copy/pasted from your comment actually has two extra hidden characters between the `d` and `4` towards the end. But assuming that's some weird artifact of copy/paste and you actually have 66 characters (`0x` and then 64 characters after that), then you have what you want. Just parse it as a hexadecimal number. `parseInt('0x00...', 16)` should work.

Comment: Note that depending on the library you use to perform the keccak function, the result may have a `0x` prefix. In this case you'd want to use `keccak_256.hex('balanceOf(address)').substr(0, 10)` to get the correct function selector which is `0x70a08231`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Etherscan api!